# If $\lim_{x\to 5} f(x) = 2$ and $\lim_{x \to 5}g(x) = 0,$ then $\lim_{x \to 5} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ does not exist. How do I prove this true or false?

Tags: calculus, limits

I feel as if this question is pulling from limit laws.

Particularly, [the quotient law](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-1/pages/2-3-the-limit-laws)

If we let lim x → 5 f(x) be L and lim x → 5 f(x) = 0 be M that would mean the quotient law would be violated because M cannot equal zero.

But I don't feel like that's proof enough.

I feel as if I am missing something.

Comment: $\lim f(x)/g(x)$ can exist if $f(x)\to 0$ and $g(x)\to 0.$ The limit laws only tell you what can happen when $M\neq 0,$ they don't deny the possibility of the limit existing when $M=0.$

Comment: You're close. One of the first tricks you have to learn when proving something is how to turn your intuition from working backward into a proof. So, suppose the limit did exist and was, say, $K$. Then what can you say about $K\cdot 0$ using the *product* law? Is that possible?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so you're saying the quotient law only works when M =/ 0 not that a ratio of limits can't have zero in the denominator?

Comment: You are right, that's not a proof. The quotient law can't be applied because $M=0$. But not being able to apply a theorem to prove something is true does not prove that it's false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lim_{x \to 5} f(x)/g(x) \to L'$ then $\lim_{x \to 5} f(x) = 0$ by the limit law for products.

This can be seen by writing
$$
f(x) = h(x)\cdot g(x) \quad \mbox{where} \quad h(x) = f(x)/g(x). 
$$

Then $h(x) \to L', g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 5$, and so $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 5$. This is a contradiction.

Hence $h(x)$ does not have a limit as $x \to 5$, which is what you wanted.

Comment: I'm all good up until "and so" still not seeing how f(x) equals 0.

Comment: Wait, I've got it. f(x)=L, h(x)=L', g(x)=M. Via the product law L=L' * M. L= L' * 0. Therefore L = 0.

Which we were told that it is 2. 

Did I get this right?

Comment: How did you know to do this?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You just need to arrive at a contradiction, so this approach is natural.